# What does this code return? block.timestamp / 1 days

Tags: solidity, timestamp

```
function today() private view returns (uint256) {
    return block.timestamp / 1 days;
}
```

Why do we need this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will return how many days passed since 1/1/1970

1 days = 86400 second
Epoch = 1531409238 second

Epoch/1 days= 17724 days, 15 hours, 26 minutes and 40 seconds.

This will help you to know in which day /date are you when we run this function 
1970+17724 day

Answer (score 1):

`block.timestamp` according to the [Solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=block#block-and-transaction-properties) is current block timestamp as seconds since unix epoch.

`days` is a [time unit](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/units-and-global-variables.html#time-units) built into Solidity

Dividing the time in seconds by 1 day worth of seconds returns you today

Comment: block.timestamp = 1 531 399 433 seconds
1 day = 86400 seconds
1 531 399 433 /  86400  = 17724.5304745 seconds
Dividing the time in seconds by 1 day worth of seconds returns you today.
What do you mean by "returns you today"?

Comment: Every perfect 'day' since the Unix epoch can be represented as an integer. A 'perfect day' in this scenario is something with time exactly 00:00:00

The block timestamp 1 531 399 433 is not a perfect day. The integer part of the division, 17724, is the day since the unix epoch and the decimal part represents the specific time